# using facebook connect for website on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-2

i am using Facebook connect user authentication for my website.i followed some simple tutorials but i couldn't able to make it.since i am using codeigniter  and testing it on localhost.i need to know whether Facebook allow to redirect back on localhost or not.if it does then how to work with Facebook connect on local machine.please let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `localhost` in your app settings in all the places where it want’s to know stuff like login URL, website, etc. – then it should work perfectly fine. (Except for those functions that actually need Facebook to connect your server, like deauthorize URL – put pure redirects happen client side, so there’s no problem there.)

Comment: i already tried it.but when i try to log in from localhost..after signing in it not responding

Answer (score 0):

I run a pure PHP project (so I don't know how you do this with CodeIgniter) and I got Facebook Connect working doing these 2 (that I remember; if don't, tell me and I revise :)

- edited hosts file (c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts or /etc/hosts) to redirect 127.0.0.1 to domain name you use
- set `<base href="..">` meta to

  "http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/"

then handle the URI you pass to Facebook Connect properly using the domain you set.

To test, access using `http://<the-domain-name-set-in-hosts>` and test normally. I guess that's it, and it's working here.